# np.loadtxt: could not convert string to float

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I have the following textfile:

```
13,1980,0,1,0,0,14,0,1.1975401639938354,1
13,1981,0,2,0,0,14,1,1.853060007095337,4
13,1982,0,3,0,0,14,0,1.3444616794586182,9
13,1983,0,4,0,0,14,0,1.4332133531570435,16
13,1984,0,5,0,0,14,0,1.5681251287460327,25
13,1985,0,6,0,0,14,0,1.6998909711837769,36
13,1986,0,7,0,0,14,0,-0.7202625870704651,49
```

When I try to load it into Jupyter Notebook in python:

```
data = np.loadtxt("/filepath/wagepan.txt")
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '13,1980,0,1,0,0,14,0,1.1975401639938354,1'
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? I tried looking at other posts, but the issue was not similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `delimiter` argument to define the delimiter.

```
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt("data.dat", delimiter=",")

print(data)
```

Output:

```
[[ 1.30000000e+01  1.98000000e+03  0.00000000e+00  1.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.40000000e+01  0.00000000e+00
   1.19754016e+00  1.00000000e+00]
 [ 1.30000000e+01  1.98100000e+03  0.00000000e+00  2.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.40000000e+01  1.00000000e+00
   1.85306001e+00  4.00000000e+00]
 [ 1.30000000e+01  1.98200000e+03  0.00000000e+00  3.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.40000000e+01  0.00000000e+00
   1.34446168e+00  9.00000000e+00]
 [ 1.30000000e+01  1.98300000e+03  0.00000000e+00  4.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.40000000e+01  0.00000000e+00
   1.43321335e+00  1.60000000e+01]
 [ 1.30000000e+01  1.98400000e+03  0.00000000e+00  5.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.40000000e+01  0.00000000e+00
   1.56812513e+00  2.50000000e+01]
 [ 1.30000000e+01  1.98500000e+03  0.00000000e+00  6.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.40000000e+01  0.00000000e+00
   1.69989097e+00  3.60000000e+01]
 [ 1.30000000e+01  1.98600000e+03  0.00000000e+00  7.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  1.40000000e+01  0.00000000e+00
  -7.20262587e-01  4.90000000e+01]]
```